# Hosting a git repo on AWS Amplify such that it points to the subdomain of my custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a repository A which is hosted on my domain example.com
I have another repo B which I want to be hosted on the subdomain, say xyz.example.com
How can I do that?

Comment: can you please add more details/clarity? why would you not think this is possible?  is there something you are trying and getting unexpected results?

Comment: I am having the same issue, trying to host a subdomain on aws amplify but with a different repository.
If anyone has any idea, please help.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

Take a look at what they say for connecting only a subdomain, in this link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-manage-subdomains.html

They say you should first choose the original domain (not the subdomain),

then- EXCLUDE the master branch like they show in the link.

And then you make the subdomain name change below that.

Check out the link.